# Passing Value from Sub Report To MainReport on Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm currently having a problem with regards on Crystal Report Shared Variable. this is my situation.

I have a Report consist of multiple sub reports (and of course the main report). i need to expose a value in main report from Sub Report, but the problem is i need to Display it before the sub report was rendered. Please see the image below:

[image]

As you can see the image above, i need to display the value below (Sub report with RED encircle with VALUE) on the TOP (Red encircle without value).

I used Shared Variable but i think it will not work since the TOP will be first rendered (where i need to display the Value from subreport) before the Below(where i need to get the value).

Is it possible?

Comment: With full demo
https://youtu.be/rExF77wHSzE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section that displays the value has already been rendered by the time the other section sets the value of the `shared` variable.

Two options:

- add a second instance of the subreport to a section that precedes the section when you want to display its value; you won't be able to suppress either the section or the subreport, so you will need to make the subreport as small as possible and change the font colors to white
- use a sql-expression field to calculate the desired value and avoid the subreport complexity altogether

Comment: Your first option is little bit hard to implement since im only using crystal reports for VS2010 and no "Save As Subreport" option available on this version.

your second option is also not doable since the "VALUE" is generatd from other formula inside the subreport.

anyway, 1 up for your idea :)